# Look up and Replace by Column Heading and ID in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm having trouble explaining but here's the situation I'm trying to solve:

For each respondent, I want to replace Open1 and Open2 with the values in the columns Open1 and Open2. I feel that this should be a simple solution but I've been staring at it for a while and I can't figure it out.

**Current Dataset:**

ID |   Col1     |  Col2   |  Col3  |  Col4  |  Col5  |  Open1  |  Open2  |

1  |   be rich  |buy home | pay edn | *Open1* |  Not worry | feel secure | care for parents

2 | buy home | be rich | *Open1* | *Open2* | pay medical expenses | give to causes | leave legacy

**What I want to achieve**

ID |   Col1     |  Col2   |  Col3  |  Col4  |  Col5  |  Open1  |  Open2  |

1  |   be rich  |buy home | pay edn | **feel secure** |  Not worry | feel secure | care for parents

2 | buy home | be rich | **give to causes** | **leave legacy** | pay medical expenses | give to causes | leave legacy

**DATA**
Here is the data in `dput` format.

```
df1 <-
structure(list(ID = c("1", "2"), Col1 = c("be rich", "buy home"
), Col2 = c("buy home", "be rich"), Col3 = c("pay edn", "Open1"
), Col4 = c("Open1", "Open2"), Col5 = c("Not worry", "pay medical expenses"
), Open1 = c("feel secure", "give to causes"), Open2 = c("care for parents", 
"leave legacy")), .Names = c("ID", "Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", 
"Col5", "Open1", "Open2"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <-
structure(list(ID = c("1", "2"), Col1 = c("be rich", "buy home"
), Col2 = c("buy home", "be rich"), Col3 = c("pay edn", "give to causes"
), Col4 = c("feel secure", "leave legacy"), Col5 = c("Not worry", 
"pay medical expenses"), Open1 = c("feel secure", "give to causes"
), Open2 = c("care for parents", "leave legacy")), .Names = c("ID", 
"Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5", "Open1", "Open2"), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another option:

```
df <- t(apply(df, 1, function(x) {
    x <- gsub("Open1", x["Open1"], x)
    gsub("Open2", x["Open2"], x)
}))
```

---

Data:

```
## read in table
text = "ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Open1 | Open2 
1 | be rich |buy home | pay edn | Open1 | Not worry | feel secure | care for parents
2 | buy home | be rich | Open1 | Open2 | pay medical expenses | give to causes | leave legacy"
df <- read.delim(text = text, sep = "|", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df <- sapply(df, trimws)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not particularly elegant, but it works:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
# Trim whitespace off of characters in the data provided. 
df1[] <- lapply(df1[], 
                trimws)


df_inter <- 
  df1 %>% 
  gather(col, value, 
         contains("Col"))

for(i in seq_along(df_inter$value)){
  if (df_inter$value[i] %in% names(df_inter)){
    df_inter$value[i] <- df_inter[[df_inter$value[i]]][i]
  }
}

df_inter %>% 
  dcast(ID ~ col,
        value.var = "value")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are simpler ways but the following does what you want.
First of all, I will use the data in the question posted in `dput` format. Note that it was created with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.

```
df1b <- df1    # work on a copy

df1b <- t(apply(df1b[-1], 1, function(x){
              x[grep("Open1", x)] <- x["Open1"]
              x
          }))
df1b <- t(apply(df1b, 1, function(x){
              x[grep("Open2", x)] <- x["Open2"]
              x
          }))

df1b <- as.data.frame(df1b, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df1b <- cbind(df1[1], df1b)

identical(df1b, df2)    # check the results, it works
#[1] TRUE
```

In your case you would start `df1b <- df1` with the names of your real df's, and adjust the code appropriately.